# Quoted Comma Delimited Parameter results in "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-scripting

I have spent a few hours back and forth with this and I quit! I am just trying to read in a parameter from the command-line. This was working fine until I introduced the double-quote and comma delimiters into the command-line call. Though I think the real issue is something with these commas, not sure what is happening, hopefully someone can assist? :3

The command line is this:

```
deploy.bat -pom=ui\main.pom -hostPassword=test1234 -hostInstances="myserver1.subdomain.com:150,myserver2.subdomain.com:151,myserver3.subdomain.com:153" -uploadAndInstall -useTargetBuild
```

Then in the batch file I have a section to read the parameters and call a function to pass the KEY/VAL pair into for setting a variable (if anyone knows a better way for this; please :)

```
rem parse all passed arguments
:ARGS
SET KEY=%1
SET VAL=%2
ECHO TRYING %KEY%=%VAL%
IF [%KEY%]==[] GOTO ARGE
ECHO HAVETOKEN
ECHO %KEY:~0,1%E
IF "%KEY:~0,1%"=="-" (
    ECHO HAVEKEY
    IF [%VAL%]==[] (
        ECHO NOVAL
        CALL :EARG %KEY% TRUE
    ) ELSE (
        IF "%VAL:~0,1%"=="-" (
            ECHO HAVEKEYNEXT
            CALL :EARG %KEY% TRUE
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO HAVEVAL
            CALL :EARG %KEY% %VAL%
            SHIFT /1
        )
    )
)
SHIFT /1
GOTO ARGS
:ARGE
```

The `ECHO` are basically my debugging of this; so let me copy/paste the output and you'll see where it is getting hung-up at:

```
TRYING -pom=ui\main.pom
HAVETOKEN
-E
HAVEKEY
HAVEVAL
-pom ui\main.pom
TRYING -hostPassword=test1234
HAVETOKEN
-E
HAVEKEY
HAVEVAL
-hostPassword test1234
TRYING -hostInstances="myserver1.subdomain.com:150,myserver2.subdomain.com:151,myserver3.subdomain.com:153"
HAVETOKEN
-E
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

So as you can see it knows the `-hostInstances` is there, but it will not even run this line of code (even though the line above is the same) `IF "%KEY:~0,1%"=="-" (`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It' a matter of **always** proper quoting.
- As the sub `:EArg` is missing I inserted one which prepends the keys with an underscore to ease output.

---

```
@Echo off
rem parse all passed arguments
:ARGS
SET "KEY=%~1"
SET "VAL=%~2"
IF "%KEY%"=="" GOTO ARGE
ECHO TRYING %KEY%=%VAL%
ECHO HAVETOKEN %KEY:~0,1%E
IF "%KEY:~0,1%"=="-" (
    ECHO HAVEKEY   %KEY:~1%
    IF "%VAL%"=="" (
        ECHO NOVAL
        CALL :EARG "%KEY:~1%" TRUE
    ) ELSE (
        IF "%VAL:~0,1%"=="-" (
            ECHO HAVEKEYNEXT %VAL%
            CALL :EARG "%KEY:~1%" TRUE
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO HAVEVAL   %VAL%
            CALL :EARG "%KEY:~1%" "%VAL%"
            SHIFT /1
        )
    )
)
SHIFT /1
GOTO ARGS
:EArg
Set "_%~1=%~2"
Goto :EOF
:ARGE
Set _
```

Sample output:

```
> deploy.bat -pom=ui\main.pom -hostPassword=test1234 -hostInstances="myserver1.subdomain.com:150,myserver2.subdomain.com:151,myserver3.subdomain.com:153" -uploadAndInstall -useTargetBuild
TRYING -pom=ui\main.pom
HAVETOKEN -E
HAVEKEY   pom
HAVEVAL   ui\main.pom
TRYING -hostPassword=test1234
HAVETOKEN -E
HAVEKEY   hostPassword
HAVEVAL   test1234
TRYING -hostInstances=myserver1.subdomain.com:150,myserver2.subdomain.com:151,myserver3.subdomain.com:153
HAVETOKEN -E
HAVEKEY   hostInstances
HAVEVAL   myserver1.subdomain.com:150,myserver2.subdomain.com:151,myserver3.subdomain.com:153
TRYING -uploadAndInstall=-useTargetBuild
HAVETOKEN -E
HAVEKEY   uploadAndInstall
HAVEKEYNEXT -useTargetBuild
TRYING -useTargetBuild=
HAVETOKEN -E
HAVEKEY   useTargetBuild
NOVAL
_hostInstances=myserver1.subdomain.com:150,myserver2.subdomain.com:151,myserver3.subdomain.com:153
_hostPassword=test1234
_pom=ui\main.pom
_uploadAndInstall=TRUE
_useTargetBuild=TRUE
```

Comment: Wow, thank you; how to know when to put quotes around complete variable and assignment? Or should just always do this?

Comment: To avoid trailing spaces and breaks caused by poiseneous characters - yes. Also enclosing the operands in an if with `[]` won't help if there are spaces in the var, so if ever possible use double quotes. The call with hostinstances requires quoting because the `,` would split into several arguments.